# text over Wifi using SSID

Tags: android, communication, android-wifi

It is possible to sent message over wifi using SSID,i searched and seen this **Wi-Fi peer-to-peer (P2P)API**  [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html)
  also seeing this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492362/wifi-chat-between-two-or-more-android-devices)
But there is no any SSID in **Wi-Fi peer-to-peer (P2P)API** they are not sending data over SSID they are send data using Socket 
[transfer data](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html#transferring)

> Once a connection is established, you can transfer data between the
>   devices with sockets

So my question is How i sent text using wifi SSID?

Comment: By sending text using SSID what do you mean ?

Comment: Do you want to send some information before connection is established?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean send an SMS addressed to a WiFi SSID then the answer is no, as they are two different communication systems and the SSID would not be a valid end point address in the SMS protocol.

If you simply want to send SMS over wifi (because you have no GSM/UMTS etc network connection, only Wifi) then there are a number of web based applications which will allow you do this, plus applications like Google Voices. These all essentially provide an interface into the SMS network, so the message has to be addressed ultimately with an address the SMS network (or more precisely the CCITT No.7 network) will understand - i.e. not an SSID.

If you wanted, you could create a web service that would associate an SSID with a valid SMS address (e.g. mobile number). You would need some system to keep make sure that there was a unique mapping between SSID and the mobile number, and you would have to either disallow or handle duplicate SSID's somehow. If you are not restricted to SMS then it would almost certainly be easier to use some IP based messaging system once you had the Peer to Peer direct WiFi connection established.